# How to add custom link NOT http to Wordpress menu? I want to add link viber://add?number=0000000000

Tags: wordpress

I want to add custom link NOT http to wordpress menu. But after adding, the field is automatically cleared. How to fix it? I want to add link viber://add?number=0000000000

Answer (score 2):

Appearance => Menus => Custom Links (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EODLN.png)
in functions.php add

```
add_filter( 'kses_allowed_protocols', function ( $protocols ) {
    $protocols[] = 'viber';
    return $protocols;
} );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/kses_allowed_protocols/